# Invalid operation: Data value "-1" has invalid format; Happens intermittently in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

It works sometimes and fails sometimes. I don't see any problem in data not sure why I am getting this error

```
SELECT (to_date(dd.date_dkey,'YYYYMMDD')::DATE-1) AS weekend,du.dim_user_skey,MAX(ft.rfv) AS rfv_score 
INTO #rfv5
FROM reportingdb.ft_rfv_score_weekly ft
JOIN abstraction.lkp_user lu ON lu.erights_id=ft.erights_id
JOIN abstraction.dim_date dd ON (date_trunc('week', to_date(ISNULL(dd.date,'01/01/2099'),'dd/mm/yyyy')::DATE)::Date-1)=ft.reportdate::date
JOIN  lighthousedb.dim_user du ON du.ft_user_id=lu.ft_user_id
WHERE (to_date(dd.date_dkey,'YYYYMMDD')::DATE-1) < getdate()::date AND ft.reportdate::date > (getdate()-30)
AND dd.date_dkey > 20160101 
GROUP BY (to_date(dd.date_dkey,'YYYYMMDD')::DATE-1),
du.dim_user_skey;
```

Comment: This is almost certainly due to some malformed data in one of your date columns.  Don't store your dates as text, it will only lead to problems like this.

Comment: Do not use operators with inconsistent operands. `- (minus)` will be treated as arithmetic operator and is intended to throw errors. If not syntax, it might give logically inconsistent results. Use functions like `dateadd / datediff` intended for date/datetime/timestamp.

Comment: Data type is int

Comment: @YusufHassan: It's perfectly legal to use `-` with (real) date values and integers in Redshift (and other databases): http://rextester.com/ZWUVR14940

Comment: What data type is `reportdate`? Also: `getdate()::date` can be simplified to `current_date`

Comment: @here: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html

FM prefix - fill mode (suppress leading zeroes and padding blanks)

```(to_date(dd.date_dkey,'FMYYYYMMDD')::DATE-1)```

Comment: Using this solved .I will post complete query as answer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, it's legal and syntax errors are not thrown. Yet, I've had logical inconsistencies in using `-` in expressions at around midnight, on both MySQL and Redshift which were then resolved using proper date functions.